# EXPLAIN ANALYZE and other insertion related stats for INSERT command in MYSQL (8.0.20)

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` was recently introduced for MYSQL but it only seems to work with `SELECT`. I am trying to find a similar command for `INSERT` which would print some insertion related statistics for each row that as it is inserted.

The following command does not work, but I am looking for a substitute for this.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE INSERT INTO table FROM <table>(col1, col2) values(val1, val2)
```

For some context, I am trying to insert into an AWS RDS MYSQL database using python and am looking to generate some insertion related metrics. Does it make sense to time each insertion command using python? What are some other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get EXPLAIN plans for INSERT with literal values - it should be obvious what the resulting workload will be. If not - its the sum of the carinality for each index divided by the number of records in the database + 1.

> Does it make sense to time each insertion command using python?

No.

> What are some other ways of doing this?

The DBMS is already doing this. [And logging it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html). Also the logs will differentiate between time taken waiting for other queries to release locks and the time for the DML to run whereas your python code won't.